# Javascript : calling function in one frame from another frame

Tags: javascript, function, frame, frameset

I don't think this question is as difficult as I think. I have read a lot of articles and posts about framesets and frames and calling function of one frame from another frame and all. What I am trying to achieve is to call a function in one frame from the parent window. I tried a lot of things and nothing seems working. Any help will be really appreciated. My issue is below

Basically my main page is having 3 frames, one frame is for header details which is constant), one is for menu list and another one is to load results based on user's menu selection

MainPage.jsp : Mainpage has 3 frames, of which one is source for function call (firstFrame) and another one is target of the function call (targetFrame). firstFrame contains all my menu list and when user clicks on one menu,
based on the selection results will be loaded on targetFrame. My ultimate aim is to display a 'processing' animation when user selects one menu. 
For that I need to call a function in targetFrame , which will display a div.

```
<frameset>
<frame name="firstFrame" src="firstFrame.jsp">
<frameset>
<frame name="secondFrame" src="secondFrame.jsp">
<frame id='frameid' name="targetFrame" src="target.jsp">
</frameset>
<frameset>

mainPageJSPFunction () {
This function will be called from source.jsp, which I am able to do   
successfully everytime, and this function will call a function in   
target.jsp, which is failing with error 'Object doesn't support method'   
except the very first time. For the very first time everything just works  
perfect.
}
```

firstFrame.jsp : 
firstFrame source is firstFrame.jsp and it has one source.jsp included in it which actually has all the menu links displayed.

source.jsp: 
This is my source.jsp which contains all the links. I am able to call sourceFunction() for each menu selection, from there I am able to call mainPageJSPFunction() (using parent.parent.mainPageJSPFunction()). 
All my issue starts now. Now I am trying to call targetFunction() of target.jsp from mainPageJSPFunction(). I am able to call it for the very first time. After that code is failing in mainPageJSPFunction() saying 'object doesnt support method'.
    function sourceFunction() {  }

target.jsp: 
    function targetFunction() { }

Below are some codes I tried from mainPageJSPFunction() to call targetFunction()
I have tried 
    window.frames[2].targetFunction() 
    document.getElementById(frameid).targetFunction()
    document.getElementById(frameid).contentDocument.targetFunction()
    document.getElementById(frameid).contentWindow().targetFunction()

none of the above seems working. 
Any help is much appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

i will give you the ability to communicate between parent-child frames